# Play Framework javascript file minification / hide sources

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, uglifyjs

I want to minify my self written javascripts in Play Framework 2.3.10. I started putting all my scripts to **app/assets/javascripts/***. Additionally i added the following route in **conf/routes**:

```
GET   /assets/v/*file   controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

I added the following lines to enable minification with uglify and digest.
to **plugins.sbt**:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")
```

and to **build.sbt**:

```
pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(uglify, digest)
```

Everything works like a charm. When i am requesting the website in my browser i see the minified javascript file (.min.js) and also the normal (source) javascript file (.js). The problem is that there is a source map generated and attached to the minified javascript. It links to the source file. 
How can i avoid that? Is it possible to hide / deny access to the source javascript files so that a user can just request the minified version ( even when trying to access the source file via direct url [ e.g. mypage.de/assets/v/javascripts/script.js ] ) ?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

i found a solution for my problem. I added a filter to filter out all .js files in my **app/assets/javascripts/** folder. I did this by adding

```
addSbtPlugin("com.slidingautonomy.sbt" % "sbt-filter" % "1.0.1")
```

to my **project/plugins.sbt** file. I changed the pipelineStages in the **build.sbt** to add a filter.

```
pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(uglify, digest, filter)

includeFilter in filter := new FileFilter {
  def accept(pathname: File): Boolean = {
    val path = pathname.getAbsolutePath.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
    path.contains("javascripts/functions")
  }
}

excludeFilter in filter := "*.min.js"
```

Play is now creating all minified js.min files. After that all files in **javascripts/functions** are filtered except the min.js files. I hope this helps.

Rob